# Data sent from Form to back-end gives unhandled promise - NodeJs, ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, async-await, promise

I tried to post data using `formidable` to mongoDB database but I am getting error as unhandled promise I tried but could not figure out the error...

```
const express=require("express");

const Post =require("../DB/Postmodel");
const formidable=require("formidable");
const fs=require("fs").promises;
const _ = require("lodash");

const router= express.Router();

router.get('/', ( req, res)=>{
   res.send(`hello from the other side`)
});

router.post("/create", async(req, res)=>{  
   
    try {
        const form= new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.keepExtensions= true;
        let post;
    
        form.parse(req, async(err, fields, files)=>{
            try {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    return res.status(401).send(`something went wrong : ${err}`)
                }
                 console.log(fields);
                 post= new Post(fields);
    
                if(files.postPic){
                     post.postPic.data= await fs.readFile(files.postPic.path);
                     post.postPic.contentType= files.postPic.type;
                }

               await post.save();
               console.log(post);
            
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(500).send(error)
            }
           
        })
        
       res.status(201).send(`post created ${post}`)
       
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(`cannot post : ${error}`)
    }

})


module.exports=router;
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please [edit] your question to provide the full error message.

Comment: I don't know what `form.parse()` does, but it seems you send a 201 response before its asynchronous callback even ran

Comment: form.parse is a method that comes with formidable npm-package...the package is used to upload files using node.js its like multer